# Add new properties to a mongoose model in a Next JS 13 application

Tags: mongodb, object, mongoose, next.js, model

I am building a next js app with mongodb. I have a small problem though. I want to add new properties to one of my models. For one reason or another my models remain the same even though i modify the Schema. Why is that?

I made a mongoose model.

import { Schema, models, model } from 'mongoose';

```
const DaySchema = new Schema( { 
    date: { 
        type: Date, 
    }, 
    kg: { 
        type: Schema.Types.Number, 
    }, 
    height: { 
        type: Schema.Types.Number
    }
})

const MembershipUserSchema = new Schema({ 
    details: { 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: "Membership"
    }, 
    isFrozen: { 
        type: Boolean, 
        default: false, 
    }, 
    startDate: { 
        type: Date, 
    }, 
    finishDate: { 
        type: Date, 
    }, 
    doneSessions: { 
        type: Schema.Types.Number, 
        default: 0, 
    }
})

const TrainerOptionsSchema = new Schema({ 
    trainer: { 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: "Trainer"
    }, 
    isTrainer: { 
        type: Boolean, 
        default: false, 
    }, 
    trainerProfile: { 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: "Trainer"
    }
})

const UserSchema = new Schema({ 
    username: { 
        type: String, 
        required: [ true, "Username is required"], 
    }, 
    password:  {
        type: String, 
    }, 
    email: { 
        type: String, 
    }, 
    image: { 
        type: String, 
    }, 
    trainerOptions: { 
        type: TrainerOptionsSchema,
    }, 
    grades: { 
        type: [String], 
        required: [ true, 'Grades are required']
    }, 
    membership: { 
        type: MembershipUserSchema, 
    }, 
    notifications: { 
        type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId], 
        ref: "Notification"
    }, 
    posts: { 
        type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId], 
        ref: "Post"
    }, 
    calendar: { 
        type: [ DaySchema ]
    }, 
    likedPosts: { 
        type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId], 
        ref: "Post"
    }
}); 

const User = models.User || model("User", UserSchema); 
export default User;
```

However, the doneSession is a property added after the model was defined. Sadly, this doesn't appear in the database documents.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to a new property to existing documents you will need to update them manually:

```
MembershipUser.update({}, { doneSession: 0 }, { multi: true });
```